# Вывод html в плагине WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Делаю плагин, который при вводе шорткода должен выводить слайдер. Как правильно сделать вывод html ? 
Просто к шорткоду прикрепить функцию, которая будет возвращать весь код ?

```
function slider(){
   return "<html> etc </html>";
}    
add_shortcode( 'shortcode1', 'slider' );
```

Или есть более адекватный способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Приведённый Вами способ является стандартным для WordPress. Поэтому нужно использовать именно его.

К слову, именно таким образом в темах и плагинах создаются если не все, то почти все шорткоды.